# How to define a new Fortran procedure by using generic function directly?

Tags: generics, fortran

In fact, what I want to ask is not to solve a problem, but rather to become more skilful.

Assume we have a type A such as:

```
Type A
private
    (some variant)
contains
(some procedures)
generic::f=>....     
  ! we assume the inteface is f(input)
  !  real or integer or complex :: input
endtype
```

in which `f` contains many subroutines.

Now I have another type `B` in which `A` is used.

```
Type B
private
    type(A)::oA
    ...
contains
    f2       
    ! we assume the interface is f2(otherinput,input)
    !  real :: otherinput
    !  real or integer or complex :: input
end type
```

Now I want to define the subroutine `f2` in which `f` will be called. Apart from a known type `otherinput`, we have a multiple type `input` (I am not sure if my statement is correct, but anyway).

Suddenly I realize that I need to define a lot of subroutines `f2_1,f2_2,...` according to the different types of `input`. But this is stupid since this sort of things have been considered in `f`. How to avoid this annoyance?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that there is just one fixed type for `otherinput`? What types can the `input` be? Are they normal intrinsic types or similar?

Comment: sorry for misleading. For example we consider this: real(8)::otherinput , and input can be integer(8)::input / real(8)::input / complex(8)::input

Comment: Do not use comments for important information. [edit] the question instead. BTW see also https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=201706280843199430896 why I hate using `real(8)` for double precision. But it does not matter here, I would just keep real, complex and integer for simplicity in the question.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid defining multiple `f2`'s. I see just some kludge possibilities, which are much worse.

Comment: thank you so much!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not very elegant, how about calling the generic function `f` by receiving the argument "input" by `class(*)` and selecting its type explicitly...? For example,

```
module test_m
    implicit none

    type A_t
    contains
        procedure :: f_int
        procedure :: f_real
        generic :: f => f_int, f_real
    endtype

    type B_t
        type(A_t) :: A
    contains
        procedure :: g
    endtype

contains

    subroutine f_int( me, n )
        class(A_t) :: me
        integer :: n
        print *, "f_int  : ", n
    endsubroutine

    subroutine f_real( me, x )
        class(A_t) :: me
        real :: x
        print *, "f_real :", x
    endsubroutine

    subroutine g( me, str, arg )    ! 'arg' <-> 'input'
        class(B_t) :: me
        character(*) :: str
        class(*) :: arg
        print *, "g : ", str

        select type ( arg )
        type is ( integer )
            call me % A % f( arg )  
        type is ( real )
            call me % A % f( arg )
        endselect
    endsubroutine

end module

program main
    use test_m
    implicit none
    type(A_t) :: A
    type(B_t) :: B

    call A % f( 100 )
    call A % f( 1.23 )

    call B % g( "hi", -100 )
    call B % g( "yo", -1.23 )
end
```

Result with gfortran-4.8 & 7.1:

```
 f_int  :          100
 f_real :   1.23000002    
 g : hi
 f_int  :         -100
 g : yo
 f_real :  -1.23000002
```

But the above code is as lengthy as calling specific functions (`f_int` and `f_real`) from within `select type`, so it may not be what OP is looking for...

---

A slightly different approach may be to define `f` as a specific function that receives a `class(*)` variable, use `select type` inside `f`, and then call this `f` from `g`. This might make the code simpler if `arg` is simply passed from `g` (or any other functions) to `f`.

```
module test_m
    implicit none

    type A_t
    contains
        procedure :: f_int
        procedure :: f_real
        procedure :: f
    endtype

    type B_t
        type(A_t) :: A
    contains
        procedure :: g
    endtype

contains

contains

    subroutine f_int( me, n )
        class(A_t) :: me
        integer :: n
        print *, "f_int  : ", n
    endsubroutine

    subroutine f_real( me, x )
        class(A_t) :: me
        real :: x
        print *, "f_real :", x
    endsubroutine

    subroutine f( me, arg )
        class(A_t) :: me
        class(*) :: arg

        select type ( arg )
          type is ( integer ) ; call me % f_int ( arg )
          type is ( real    ) ; call me % f_real( arg )
        endselect
    endsubroutine

    subroutine g( me, str, arg )
        class(B_t) :: me
        character(*) :: str
        class(*) :: arg

        print *, "g : ", str
        call me % A % f( arg )
    endsubroutine

end module
```

The above method can also be used for extended types, e.g.,

```
module test_m
    implicit none

    ! same definition for A_t

    type, extends(A_t) :: B_t
    contains
        procedure :: g
    endtype

contains

    ! same definition for f_int, f_real, and f

    subroutine g( me, str, arg )
        class(B_t) :: me
        character(*) :: str
        class(*) :: arg

        print *, "g : ", str
        call me % A_t % f( arg )
    endsubroutine

end module
```

But I hope there is some other way for directly passing `arg` to the generic function `f` without using `select type`.

Comment: excellent, almost exactly what I want. I never know an intrinsic type can be put into type is (*). And I think the first approach looks so cute.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant by the kludge which is even worse. Notably it brings run-time polymorphism where it could otherwise be compile-time.

Comment: @VladimirF Is run-time polymorphism in Fortran so costly? Though static generics would be of course more efficient, I guess it may be an option depending on cases... (e.g., when the call is not in a heavy loop). Otherwise, performance may be of more concern...

Comment: Not too much. For functions that do more work it will not matter. But as a design it is much uglier that the think it tries to avoid.

Comment: Yes, I believe that we can write it much more compactly in other languages. So I hope more enhancement on generics will be introduced into future Fortran...

Comment: I agree with @Vladimir F, this will make the program slow(even not too much). To override the function will only increase the compiling time. In core part of the calculation, one should not do it like this. Besides, in many cases, we would only want to save our lifetime.